# JSF2 (PrimeFaces) Can I submit/update all fields from a form when I use ajax call?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form with a couple operations and fields that need to refresh almost everything when i change a value from a field. I can not put a button because it works like an excel worksheet.

Is there anyway that i can submit all fields and update all fields in my ajax action instead of:

```
<p:ajax event="blur" update="fieldX,fieldY..." process="@this,fieldB,fieldC..." listener="#{simulator.operations}"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<p:ajax event="blur" update="@form" process="@form" listener="#{simulator.operations}"/>
```